# How to call to method with jquery id sellector from template in angualr2?

Tags: angular

I would like to pass an id selector to a method from a template is it possible?

```
<ul>
  <div id="temp">some text</div>
  <button (click)="methodName1(is it possible somehow? --> $('#temp'))">Label</button>     
</ul>
```

Comment: Just pass the selector as string '#temp' and use it inside your component logic like `methodName1(selector: string) { // $(selector) somewhere}`

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass from html, actually you can call the selector inside your controller where your "methodName1" method resides.

Comment: How? Can you share an example?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use property from your typescript, like

```
<ul>
<div id="{{tempID}}">some text</div>
 <button (click)="click()">Label</button>     
</ul>
```

In your Typescript

```
tempID = 'some id'
click() {
// use tempID here
}
```

Can you please explain, what exactly you are trying to do? Angular2 is not exactly using jQuery inside templates and normally it works. It may essential for you to use jQuery, but would like to know the use case.